# What kind of question is this?

Tags: word, anagram

Together I am four and five.  Apart, am I four or five?  Often I am written one or one.  Confused, I may be payments for a bard, antique hearing-aids, the price of gas, brightly-burning fat, a damned man's ogle, guidelines for heroism, a tempting meal, a whimsical shine, a predictor of problems, a prenatal jape, or I may tamper with explosives.  What kind of question is this?  Programs and pop-quizzes frequently ask.

**Hints:**

> "four and five" refers to the number of vowels and consonants in the answer.  "four or five" refers to the number of letters in each of the two words.  The "confused" clues all refer to anagrams of the main answer.

Comment: What kind of question is this? Answer: multiple choice.

Comment: @Lawrence - No, but your thinking is in the right place...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What kind of question is this?

> **True/False**

Together I am four and five.

> As per the hint, "True/False" has four vowels and five consonants.

Apart, am I four or five?

> As per the hint, **true** has four letters and **false** has five.

Often I am written one or one.

> Often written as "T or F".

Confused, I may be payments for a bard,

> lute fares

antique hearing-aids,

> ear flutes

the price of gas,

> fuel rates

brightly-burning fat,

> suet flare

a damned man's ogle,

> faust leer

guidelines for heroism,

> feat rules

a tempting meal,

> feast lure

a whimsical shine,

> fae luster

a predictor of problems,

> fault seer

a prenatal jape,

> fetal ruse

or I may tamper with explosives.

> alter fuse

Also, it might be a land contract:

> turf lease

or a judge of respectful gestures:

> salute ref

or that burning sensation you get in your ears when woodwinds play a very fast glissando:

> flute sear

Comment: +1 because you beat me to it. I got some missing answers, so that's why I've undeleted mine. I'm missing one, though. I can re-delete mine once yours is complete.

Comment: Yes, still missing a few, but +1 for adding another to the list.

Comment: @Mythi I have a few missing too (more than you), so I haven't necessarily beat you to it.  But from what I have seen around here, posting partial answers for questions like these is acceptable.  Is it not?

Comment: I've seen partials done before. Not sure how to handle our situation, but I feel like removing mine later out of courtesy and sense of tidiness. Let's finish first.

Comment: Not sure which to accept since there was a bit of back and forth with partial answers, though this one was first by a small margin.  Fix the "one or one" clue (per @histocrat's comment in the other answer) and I'll award this one.

Answer (score 5):

The question is

> **true/false**

*Together I am four and five. Apart, am I four or five?*

> Darrel H provided this in his hint. Together, the answer is composed of four vowels and five consonants. Separately and respectively, they are four and five letters.

*Often I am written one or one.*

> As a boolean data type, true can equal "1". Some further explanation I'm not sure about...

*Confused, I may be payments for a bard*

> lute fares

*antique hearing-aids*

> ear flutes

*the price of gas*

> fuel rates

*brightly-burning fat*

> suet flare

*a damned man's ogle*

> Faust leer

*guidelines for heroism*

> feat rules

*a tempting meal*

> feast lure

*a whimsical shine*

> fae luster

*a predictor of problems*

> fault seer

*a prenatal jape*

> fetal ruse

*or I may tamper with explosives*

> alter fuse

Comment: Main answer is correct.  Almost there - only 2 clues missing...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I know one is the "whimsical shine". Which is the other clue, please?

Comment: Your "one or one" answer is not quite what I was thinking.  I suppose that answer still works from a programmer's perspective...

Comment: My guess is you were going for "T or F" for that one.

Comment: Also, suggested an edit for "whimsical shine" (snr yhfgre).

Comment: Yeah, unless you meant something like "written as one or the other" or marked as a tick in a test sheet, I don't know. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! I kept getting hung up on "artful see" or "fete something". Thanks, @histocrat!

Comment: And @histocrat capped it off.  Good work.  (This was the first one I've posted - it was tricky finding the fine line between "too cryptic" and "too easy".  Not sure if that Hints section overdid it...)

Answer (score -1):

This question is...

> Convergent

Meaning...

> There are very few possible answers. In this case, there is only one (convergent)

This also means that...

> The only part in your question that was relevant was the end. The rest were merely red herrings.

Comment: Sorry, nope.  Every part of the question (including the title) is a clue.

Comment: @Darrel Can't blame me for trying :)